# Android keyboard seems to toggle jquery .slideToggle, anyone know a fix?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm currently developing a site where I hide the header in mobile devices, it can be opened using a anchor with a jquery slideToggle function. Great stuff. Inside the header there's a search field and some other buttons.

However, when I focus the input on android and the virtual keyboard opens up my header closes. hiding the search field and everything else in it.

I have come to the conclusion that it is the keyboard that toggles this "bug".

Have anyone ever seen this before? I have no clue what I'm even looking for. Bloody android! :)

Thanks,
Robin

---

```
var searchToggle = $('.search-toggle'),
    subHeader = $('.sub-header');

searchToggle.click(function(){
    subHeader.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Which method fires the jQuery script?

Comment: click I guess, as soon as the keyboard opens.

Comment: Could you post the code for the script so we can better help you out? :) Thanks.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Added the script to the question above, this is the only part that is related to the header.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks here's a video of me testing the issue:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0VcWW3WHME&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Found out that when the keyboard opens up the window trigger a resize function I used.